# Prevent fsck on every boot

Tags: boot, fsck, systemd, fedora-18

I'm analyzing boot times with systemd-analyze and, after optimizing it as far as I could, I noticed fsck-ing every partition on boot sometimes take up to 20 seconds. I feel it's unnecessary since I have never had problems and data on this computer is not vital.

Is there any way to stop this unneeded behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I missunderstand the question, this is realy simple and there alot of information on how to do this out there.

Anyway, disable fsck is quite simple and could be done in several ways, where I think fstab is the best way to do it permanent. Have a look at [this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bypassing-fsck/) over at nixCraft, it's very straight forward. Basically change the last value to 0 in the device list in /etc/fstab for the devices that you want to change behavior on, that is. More information could also be found in the fstab manual (*man fstab* from the command line.)

Comment: The "fastboot" method does not work, but editing fstab has solved.

Comment: Actually, it still does fsck on root directory, but at least it just fsck 50GB and not all the disk.